# Regarding Graphical issues and performance In ubuntu 14.04 LTS server with GUI

Tags: server, graphics

I am having some issues with my Dell T630 server with 288GB of RAM 16 core processor and 2 GB of Matrox G200 Graphics. Ubuntu just runs horribly.

Every window I open just lags while opening. I've already tried to to turn off window animation using Unity, but Unity doesn't seem to apply any changes that I make.

Ubuntu is practically unusable at this point. Can anyone help me with these issues?

Information about my graphics setup (`inxi -G`):

```
Card:           Matrox Systems G200eR2 
X.Org:          1.15.1 
drivers:        mga (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) 
Resolution:     1440x900@60.0hz 
GLX Renderer:   Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.4, 256 bits) 
GLX Version:    2.1 Mesa 10.1.3
```

Comment: From a terminal (CTRL+ALT+T) or TTY (CTRL+ALT+F1; back to GUI with CTRL+ALT+F7), you could run `sudo apt-get install inxi` and then post the output of `inxi -G` by [edit]ing your question. That will show some more information about your used graphics card and driver, which I think is the problem's cause.

Comment: This what it shows after the inxi -G command <br/> Graphics:  Card: Matrox Systems G200eR2 X.Org: 1.15.1 drivers: mga (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) Resolution: 1440x900@60.0hz 
           GLX Renderer: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.4, 256 bits) GLX Version: 2.1 Mesa 10.1.3

Comment: Use the following command to fix this issue
1.switch to console mode: Alt+Ctrl+F1
2.kill x server: sudo service lightdm stop
3.generate new xorg.conf file: sudo X -configure -- this will create xorg.conf.new file in your current dir
4.rename and move: sudo mv xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf
5.open /etc/X11/xorg.conf, replace the graphic driver of 'mga' with 'vesa'
6.return to GUI: sudo start lightdm

Comment: Please don't write this as comment. Write it as answer instead and accept it afterwards, as it solved your problem. That way future readers with a similar problem may also profit from, your solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following command to fix this issue

1. Switch to console mode (TTY1):

   <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
2. Kill lightdm service:

   ```
   sudo service lightdm stop
   ```
3. Generate new `xorg.conf.new` file in the current directory:

   ```
   sudo X -configure
   ```
4. Move and rename the file:

   ```
   sudo mv xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf
   ```
5. Open `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`, replace the graphic driver `mga` with `vesa`
6. Return to GUI:

   ```
   sudo start lightdm
   ```

Comment: Does `sudo service lightdm stop` kill the x server? It stops the lightdm service, which I think is not the same...

Comment: I dont think it kills the X server. but the lagging issues with the GUI works fine after changing the config file

Comment: But you wrote that it kills the x server as step #2... Maybe you should look that up again?

Comment: Ya it is not killing the X server, it just stops the dmservice