# bamfdaemon causing performance issues in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, unity, performance

Recently I've been having performance issues (sluggish switching between workspaces, icons not being removed from tray upon closing, etc...) on my computer which runs **Ubuntu 14.04**.

I've found the culprit to be a process called **bamfdaemon** because a kill command temporarily resolves the issues.

However, after a short time, it always comes back and running a `top` command shows that it holds a steady **99-100%** CPU.

Any ideas?

Comment: did you see anything weird in /var/log/syslog?

Comment: Just checked, I'm not seeing anything strange or related to bamfdaemon

Comment: Have you tried an `apt-get install --reinstall bamfdaemon`?

Answer (score 1):

From [What does `bamfdaemon` do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/260734/what-does-bamfdaemon-do)

> When you launch/execute/open a desktop program/application: 
>  Unity will either pop up a new icon on the launcher(dock) and/or add an arrow to an existing icon. Each icon is not an executable; it is a .desktop file. bamfdaemon helps this by determining whether an arrow needs to be added to an existing icon, or a new icon be popped up, along with other behaviors dependent on application identity.

And also, it does many other helping tasks in regards to help GUI to provide nice user experience. So killing this will not work, as first of all it is a daemon process, by nature it will be re-spawned by system. Also it can cause severe issue with your GUI as it could mess that up!

*Solution to this is not simple as re-installation or removal of component.*
I suggest two methods here...

- [Increase Unity Performance](https://www.techdrivein.com/2013/03/4-simple-tweaks-to-improve-unity-performance-ubuntu.html) or [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/).
- [Change Desktop Interface](https://askubuntu.com/questions/413569/whats-the-lightest-ubuntu-desktop-environment) **OR** Try any of these [Linux Desktop Environments](https://www.tecmint.com/best-linux-desktop-environments/)

**NOTE**: Before you try any of above link...

- If you have lesser amount RAM, (I'm not sure how much amount of RAM sufficient to run Unity smoothly!), then better go for second option, choose any light-weight desktop interface.
- If less RAM is not the case and system has graphics card, then I guess changing driver in `Xorg` configuration can do some improvement in performance. (This suggestion is after reading [Graphical issues and performance In ubuntu 14.04 LTS server with GUI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/673968/regarding-graphical-issues-and-performance-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts-server-with-gui/674656) answer to this)

Not sure much about this NOTE in your case! But could be helpful to others, may be!)